# GNU parallel --semaphore gets stuck after Ctrl-C and doesn't release --id

Tags: docker, gnu-parallel

I am a pretty new user to GNU parallel and I'm running sem (GNU parallel --semaphore) in the following bash script using the windows subsystem for linux:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS=,
while read -r col1 col2 col3 col4; do
  echo "started"
  sem --id mutex_1a -j+0 docker run --rm --gpus=all -v "/mnt/c/Work/Imaging/Data/dicomsSorted/$col1:/ukbdata/$col1" fbp:version1 ./runScripts.sh $col1 2 -a stdout;
done < "/mnt/c/Work/Imaging/Data/forPipeline/pidAgeSexSite.csv"
echo "waiting"
sem --wait --id mutex_1a
echo "finished"
```

As you can see, it calls sem with the --id mutex_1a and runs a docker container called fbp:version1, mounting a directory and runnning ./runScripts with a couple of arguments. Ordinarily this produces 12 "started" echos and runs through each in parallel.

This works fine but if I ever break out of it with Ctrl-C and then try to restart it then it doesn't run. It runs a single 'echo started"' but doesn't actually start a container. I think it is waiting for the --id mutex_1a to be released at the end of the job.

Is there a way to tell sem not to wait anymore and to release the --id?

Tried:
Neither restarting docker or wsl releases the --id.

This occurs even with a completely different set of inputs to $col1, so different mnt folders and parameters given to ./runScripts.sh.

Changing ids to mutex_1b and mutex_1c does restore the normal behaviour but I'm worried about the longevity of this strategy and I can't go in and manually change the id each time it is disrupted.

Comment: Would this be easier to write and maintain using a higher-level language and a Docker client API?  Can you `docker run -d` the containers in the background, so you don't need Parallel to manage them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove `~/.parallel/semaphores/id-mutex_1a`.

To avoid this you might want to re-write your script:

```
doit() {
  col1=$1
  col2=$2
  col3=$3
  col4=$4
  echo Started
  docker run --rm --gpus=all -v "/mnt/c/Work/Imaging/Data/dicomsSorted/$col1:/ukbdata/$col1" fbp:version1 ./runScripts.sh $col1 2 -a stdout
}
export -f doit

parallel --colsep ',' doit < "/mnt/c/Work/Imaging/Data/forPipeline/pidAgeSexSite.csv"
```